# Change discord bot nickname (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have a simple issue that I'm yet to figure out, how can I change my bot's own nickname, because I want to display information instead of its nickname continuously.

tried  this :

> await bot.user.edit(username=price)

but this actually changes the username which is not allowed to be done multiple times.

```
async def status_update():
    while True:
        price = str(get_BTC_price(ws))
        await bot.user.edit(username=price)
        await asyncio.sleep (2)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.loop.create_task(status_update())
```

Thanks

Comment: Problem resolved : `ctx.guild.me.edit(nick="new nickname here")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicknames are tied to [*Guild Members*](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member). In order to change your bot's nickname, you must

1. Get the Guild Member object for your bot
2. Use [`<Member>.edit(nick=nick)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.edit)

Note that this will only change the nickname for one server. If you wanted it to be global you would have to loop through each guild and perform the operation (expensive). You may want to use the *status* box instead to convey this information.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer I'll try your solution and give feedback. 
Yeah I used the status box to display this information, but I find it more convenient if it's on the nickname, my bot is only on 1 guild so It won't cost alot to do so.

Comment: Best of luck. If you do end up using this please mark it as correct so others can find it :)

Comment: Solved it using 
        `await ctx.guild.me.edit(nick="new nickname here")`


Thanks for your help